# Bootstrap collapsible breaks on combox select change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My collapsible div looks like this and it collapse/expand on clicking `btnCollapse`.

As soon as I change the selection in dropdown, the collapsible div stop expanding. What am I doing wrong ? Any hints please ?

```
<div class="panel-heading" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
   <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" id="btnCollapse" href="#collapse1" style="float:right;">Hide Filter</a>
   </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
   <div class="col-sm-6">
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.SelectedCat,new SelectList(Model.Cat, "Id", "Name"),"Select ..",new { @class= "form-control" })
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 3...or Bootstrap 4? You've got both tagged and *one* of them is clearly wrong.

Comment: Which version of bootstrap are you using - you tagged the question with both versions? Just to exclude the dropdown as source of the bug try switching with other content, but I don't think that is the issue. And are you trying to create a Accordion component, if so you are using it wrong?

Comment: i am using bootstrap 3